# How to use 'create!' method on a class with a constructor that takes one argument

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a class that look like this (simplified)

```
class Timereg < ActiveRecord::Base

  def initialize(hour_id)
    super()
    self.hour_id = hour_id
    self.status = -2
    self.slug = SecureRandom.uuid.to_s
  end
end
```

When using it like this

```
Timereg.new(1)
```

all is good.

How can I use it with this

```
Timereg.create!
```

I can't figure out the syntax. I get:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Comment: What's your Rails version?

Answer (score 4):

It is a bad idea to override `create` or `initialize` methods.

You should use [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). You can use `after_initialize` hook to assign the values.

Comment: I think I will go with the callbacks. But should it not be added that it is only a bad idea when inheriting form a ActiveRecord class? Initialize is OK with other classes I suspect

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the block parameter:

```
def initialize(hour_id, &block)
  super(nil, &block)
  ..
end
```

This is what ActiveRecord's `create!` looks like:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb, line 47
def create!(attributes = nil, &block)
  if attributes.is_a?(Array)
    attributes.collect { |attr| create!(attr, &block) }
  else
    object = new(attributes, &block)
    object.save!
    object
  end
end
```

Because your `.new` does not take two parameters, the `create!` fails.

But as @kartikey-tanna [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50561061/681520), it may not be a good idea to modify the initializer in the first place.

Consider something like:

```
def self.create_for_hour_id!(hour_id, attributes = nil)
  timereg = new(attributes)
  timereg.hour_id = hour_id
  yield timereg if block_given?
  timereg.save!
  timereg
end
```

And use the callbacks to set up the slugs, status, etc:

```
before_validation :generate_slug

private
def generate_slug
  self.slug ||= SecureRandom.uuid.to_s
end
```

Comment: Hmm. But my idea is to protect the slug creation and status , it should not be up to the user to set it these

Comment: The callbacks should be used for that

Comment: Is it correct that if you make a line like this self.status = -2 (forgetting the || signs) that it will set this attribute to -2 every time? Since I used after_initialize. Maybe after_create only gets create called once and not on every save?

Comment: I think `after_initialize` will be triggered even for `Timereg.find(123)`. I haven't used rails in ages.

Comment: If that is the case it really quite different form having it in the constructor. Gonna stick to after_create and check if it is already not set. Or maybe just remove at all and just set it manually when I create, just thought there would be a easy simple way to guard me from my self